# Sphere close packing with cubic sheet

Tags: spheres, packing-problem

In some book, it's written that layers making the 3d structure must be hexagonal for close packing of spheres. But suppose we have a simple cubic sheet and another one on top of it, with which  we try to fill depression between spheres.

By calculation, I get that minimal distance between layers is $\sqrt2r$ and calculating efficiency from this structure and taking unit cell as what comes out to be effectively end centric with $Z=2$, $a=b=2r$ and $C=2^{3/2}r$. I get exactly the ratio calculated by Gauss. Is there a discrepancy of some kind regarding close packing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no contradiction. What you describe is the [face-centered cubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-packing_of_equal_spheres#FCC_and_HCP_Lattices)  packing, which is one of two most regular lattice packings of spheres with optimal density.

[image: fcc packing]

It can also look hexagonal from a different angle: see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_packing#Dense_packing).

Comment: Oh! so same packing looks simple cubic layers from one side and HCP layers from another?

Comment: @Mrigank: No, HCP and FCC are different. Please see [Close packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-packing_of_equal_spheres) Wikipedia article.