# cramming balls into a container: getting the most in

Tags: geometry

looking at apples in an apple bin the other day, i noticed that some people pack apples(or oranges, or tangerines, anything round) into containers using two different ways: some lay the first layer down as squares, and then put the next layer in on top, making sure that the balls are fitting at the lowest points. some also use hexagonal packing, doing a similar thing. i know that the hexagonal packing in the second dimension is the most compact. is it the same in 3 dimensions? what way goes in higher-dimensions?

Comment: This is known as the [sphere-packing problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_packing). The linked Wikipedia article should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these packings are equally efficient in 3 dimensions. Intuitively, if you have balls arranged in a square lattice, this plane is less efficient than a triangular lattice. However, when you stack layers on top of each other, the square lattices have "larger holes" so the extra layers pack more closely together. You can actually study these in chemical and material engineering courses, I briefly learned about this in my first semester at university!

To prove that they are equally efficient, all you have to do is realise that the gaps between spheres are the same. In the square case, each "gap" is contained by four spheres in the same plane, and then one more sphere below and above it. But now change your orientation slightly, and think of the sphere and top and two adjacent spheres in your "layer". These three spheres make up a tight triangle, just the same way as if you were to pack spheres from a triangular base layer. Therefore all of the gaps are expected to be the same size.

This is of course not a proof, but any proof can be carried out with ordinary trigonometry and it's just... tedious.

These are called the "face centered cubic" and "hexagonal close packed" packings, and were conjectured to be the most efficient ways of packing 3d space a long time ago. Surprisingly it was only proven at the turn of the century (and using a lot of computation) that no other packing in 3d has a greater average density! I believe we don't know much at all about packings in higher dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

If you could pack an infinite number of oranges throughout space, the two methods of close packing would give the same "density" of oranges,
assuming all oranges are perfect spheres of the same radius.
The difference that you observe is which way the packing is oriented with respect to the floor of the bin.

The arrangement of square layers over square layers is called face-centered cubic packing. Consider three mutually tangent oranges, one from an upper layer and two from the layer beneath it, and take the plane through the centers of those three oranges. The oranges whose centers are on that plane will be in hexagonal close packing in that plane.
The people who arrange the bottom layer of oranges in hexagonal close packing have simply opted to make that plane parallel to the floor of the bin.

If you examine the packing method that lays the oranges in hexagonal close packing on the floor of the bin, you may notice that we have two choices for where to put the first orange of the next layer. We can take any hexagonal close packing of space and "shift" some of the layers by making that choice differently for that layer. This produces a less-regular packing with the same density.

Also see [this other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1706414/139123)
and [the relevant article in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-packing_of_equal_spheres#FCC_and_HCP_Lattices).